# How can I delete some checkboxes and create another checkboxes with a single button?

Tags: python, checkbox, tkinter

I'm new in python and I'm trying to make a quiz in which the user check a checkbox, and then, by pressing a button, delete those checkboxes and create different ones. The problem is that I can't find the way to do it.

I've tried by typing the name of the command that the button will run and then-" .delete, .remove, .del, .destroy".
I tried with all of them, but maybe I'm using it wrong.

I don't want to disable them because I want the to disappear and appear with a single button.

```
from tkinter import *

#Screen
screen  = Tk()
screen.title("Prueba n° 1.000.000.000")
screen.geometry("500x250")

#Functions
def b_next():
    #I don't know what to write here

def del_cb():
    quit()


#1° Questions
c_1 = Checkbutton(text = "1° Option")
c_1.place(y = 20, x = 125)

c_2 = Checkbutton(text = "2° Option")
c_2.place(y = 40, x = 125)

c_3 = Checkbutton(text = "3° Option")
c_3.place(y = 60, x = 125)

c_4 = Checkbutton(text = "4° Option")
c_4.place(y = 80, x = 125)

c_5 = Checkbutton(text = "5° Option")
c_5.place(y = 100, x = 125)


#2° Questions
c_6 = Checkbutton(text = "6° Option")
c_6.place(y = 20, x = 125)

c_7 = Checkbutton(text = "7° Option")
c_7.place(y = 40, x = 125)

c_8 = Checkbutton(text = "8° Option")
c_8.place(y = 60, x = 125)

c_9 = Checkbutton(text = "9° Option")
c_9.place(y = 80, x = 125)

c_10 = Checkbutton(text = "10° Option")
c_10.place(y = 100, x = 125)


#Buttons
b_next = Button(text = "Siguiente Pregunta", command = b_next).place(y = 125, x = 125)

b_del = Button(text = "Borrar", command = del_cb).place(y = 155, x = 125)


screen.resizable (False, False)
screen.mainloop()
```

I hope you can help with this tiny problem!

P.D: I'm not very good at writing in english so there may be some grammar mistakes, sorry for that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use .pack_forget() to hide tkinter widgets.
You can use .pack() to make tkinter widgets re-appear.

E.g. to hide 'c_9':

```
c_9.pack_forget()
```

E.g. to reveal 'c_9':

```
c_9.pack()
```

---

To make a button hide or reveal tkinter widgets such as 'c_9' you can make the command of the button a subroutine that uses .pack() or .pack_forget() to hide the widget.

---

For example:

The button 'b_hide_c_9' below, runs the subroutine 'hide_c_9' when clicked.

The subroutine 'hide_c_9' hides 'c_9' using .pack_forget():

```
b_hide_c_9 = Button(text = "Hide c_9", command = hide_c_9).place(y = 155, x = 125)

def hide_c_9():
    c_9.pack_forget()
```

---

For example:

The button 'b_reveal_c_9' below, runs the subroutine 'reveal_c_9' when clicked.

The subroutine 'reveal_c_9' reveals 'c_9' using .pack_():

```
b_reveal_c_9 = Button(text = "Reveal c_9", command = reveal_c_9).place(y = 155, x = 125)

def reveal_c_9():
    c_9.pack()
```

Comment: YES! I didin't know this at all. Thank you!